# While storing time mysql database it is converting the time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql2

I want to store the date and time in mysql2 database,the time which I want to store is in GMT zone, but after saving the time is getting converted in other zone,

Can any one tell how to change the mysql2 timezone.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set global time zone in mysql. Use following link command to set it to gmt:

```
SET GLOBAL time_zone = timezone;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is specific to Rails, set the default time zone in your configuration:

**Application.rb**

`config.time_zone       = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'`

Answer (score 0):

A number of ways:

1. start the server with the '--timzeone' paramter, in this case, it would be `--timezone=UTC`.
2. You can set the `TZ` environment variable.
3. Start the server with the `--default-global-timezone` paramter, set to UTC.
4. At the start of every connection, issue a `SET time_zone = GMT`.